# Any idea what these outdoor shades are called?

Tags: outdoor, blinds

[image: outdoor shades]

Hi any idea with the name of the outdoor shades are called? Note the rope that is tied to the metal boat dock stirrup thing. They are mounted on the outside.

I've been searching for weeks and have no idea what they are called or how to find them.

I have seen people use them for privacy and also for when they close up their house for the winter.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: google `outdoor blinds`

Comment: I did nothing like this comes up

Comment: Exterior roller shades or outdoor roll up shades. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=outdoor++sun+porch+roll+up+shades&t=fpas&ia=web

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=outdoor+blinds&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images